# How to show MySql vertical table to horizontal in Codeigniter?

Tags: html-table, codeigniter-2

I want to fetch the data from MYSQL Table and display the data in the HTML table as shown in the "HTML table" picture.

MySql Table
[MySql Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2NBp.png)

HTML Table
[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZSL7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume data is

```
$data = array(
            array(
            'id'=>1,
            'name'=>'s1',
            'product_name'=>'p1',
            'month'=>'jan,2018',
            'quantity'=>12
            ),
            array(
            'id'=>2,
            'name'=>'s2',
            'product_name'=>'p2',
            'month'=>'jan,2018',
            'quantity'=>1
            ),
            array(
            'id'=>3,
            'name'=>'s3',
            'product_name'=>'p3',
            'month'=>'feb,2018',
            'quantity'=>12
            ),
            array(
            'id'=>4,
            'name'=>'s4',
            'product_name'=>'p4',
            'month'=>'feb,2018',
            'quantity'=>12
            ),
            array(
            'id'=>4,
            'name'=>'s4',
            'product_name'=>'p4',
            'month'=>'Mar,2018',
            'quantity'=>12
            )
            );
```

Create Dynamic Header

```
$header = array();
foreach($data as $val){
$header = array_unique(array_values(array_merge($header,array_keys($val))));
}
```

Add key month value as key with quantity value

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        $data[$key][$val['month']] = $val['quantity'];
    }
```